# For loop question in python about printing the columns first then printing the row

Tags: python, loops, math, rows

I have a programme that can help me to calculate some values.
And the result of this output is like a triangle.

```
S = [0.06,0.0645,0.068,0.071,0.0736,0.0756,0.0777]

n = len(S)

print(('{:0.4f} ' * n).format(*S))  # print initial line

for i in range(1,n):                # loop over rows
    for j in range(i+1, n+1):       # then over columns
        num = (1 + S[j -1])**j      # Calculating x by a certain formula
        den = (1 + S[i - 1])**i     # Calculating x by a certain formula
        x = (num/den)**(1/(j - i)) -1       # Calculating x by a certain formula and get the value of x
        print('{:0.4f}'.format(x), end=' ') # print all the values followed with a space 
    print('')                       # add a newline after a full row
```

If I run the codes above, I will have

```
0.0600 0.0645 0.0680 0.0710 0.0736 0.0756 0.0777 
0.0690 0.0720 0.0747 0.0770 0.0787 0.0807 
0.0750 0.0775 0.0797 0.0812 0.0830 
0.0801 0.0821 0.0833 0.0850 
0.0841 0.0849 0.0867 
0.0857 0.0880 
0.0904
```

But what if I only got the first column (of the result after running my programme) as my input, that is

```
0.0600 
0.0690 
0.0750 
0.0801 
0.0841 
0.0857 
0.0904
```

How could I restore the whole table (i.e. the whole triangle) by modifying the original codes and INVERSE OPERATION of the formula? Do I need to add a new for loop on the original codes?

---

In other words,
if I was given a formula x = ((((1 + k[j - 1])**j) / ((1 + k[i - 1])**i))**(1/(j-i))) - 1 , which is inside the programme.
Then, let us assume that I can get a result of

```
1 2 3     #the numbers (1 - 6) represents the order of being printed
4 5
6
```

but how could I changing the format of my triangle from a pattern above to a pattern

```
1 4 6     #the numbers (1 - 6) represents the order of being printed
2 5
3
```

BY INVERSE OPERATION of the formula?

Comment: Mate, is this your homework?

Comment: It is related to my study but it is not my homework. Our teacher only tells me the formula and expects me to calculate those value one by one. And thus I want to have a programme that can help me to calculate. Otherwise I will have to do it many many times by hand :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general terms:

1. instead of printing each line, save each entry from that line into a list
2. instead of printing a new line in the outer loop, create a new list and save the previous one within another "results" list.
3. loop over this two-dimensional list, reverse, sort or whatever, and print it however you like

And in more concrete terms:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

S = [0.06,0.0645,0.068,0.071,0.0736,0.0756,0.0777]

n = len(S)

results = []
results += [S]

for i in range(1,n):                # loop over rows
    line = []
    for j in range(i+1, n+1):       # then over columns
        num = (1 + S[j -1])**j      # Calculating x by a certain formula
        den = (1 + S[i - 1])**i     # Calculating x by a certain formula
        x = (num/den)**(1/(j - i)) -1       # Calculating x by a certain formula and get the value of x
        line += [x]
    results += [line]


for line in results:
    for entry in line:
        print(entry, end='')
    print('')

print("-" * 10)
for line in zip_longest(*results):
    for entry in line:
        if entry is not None:
            print(entry, end=' ')
    print('')
```

```
0.060.06450.0680.0710.07360.07560.0777
0.069019103773584780.072022613109848480.074691975296487630.077027177187337430.07874744277738710.08067860239842739
0.075034561087013340.077539689995302920.079709843727620910.081193329041452820.08302571799174219
0.080050656549259140.082055104262303670.083254082397003830.08503277149878619
0.084063271995895580.084859356567028140.08669857831554517
0.085656025744853540.08801863286709821
0.09038638150035694
----------
0.06 0.06901910377358478 0.07503456108701334 0.08005065654925914 0.08406327199589558 0.08565602574485354 0.09038638150035694
0.0645 0.07202261310984848 0.07753968999530292 0.08205510426230367 0.08485935656702814 0.08801863286709821
0.068 0.07469197529648763 0.07970984372762091 0.08325408239700383 0.08669857831554517
0.071 0.07702717718733743 0.08119332904145282 0.08503277149878619
0.0736 0.0787474427773871 0.08302571799174219
0.0756 0.08067860239842739
0.0777
```

I will leave the number formatting to you.

Comment: Bro, thank you for your answer. But this answer is not useful for me. It's my fault not saying clear in the question.

The idea is not sorting or ranking the position. It is about recover and restore.
For example, I have a equation x = y + 1 and I can get 
1 2 3 
4 5 
6
using this equation if my input is given  as 0, 1, 2 ,3, 4.

Comment: Okay. And now I have got the programme and I am able to print the above triangle.
Then, what if my input given is 1, 4, 6 only?
How am I able to restore my whole triangle by a new prgramme?
That is, how to restore my triangle by reversingly using the equation such that:  If I was given 1,2,3 as the initial input, how could I able to reversingly calculating the triangle from
1
2
3
to
1 4 6
2 5 
3

Comment: It seems that I cannot add a line break freely in the comment section, but I hope you can understand what I am saying.....

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my words above. What I mean is the first column should be 0.0600, 0.0690, 0.0750, 0.0801, 0.0841, 0.0857, 0.0904 instead of 0.06,0.0645,0.068,0.071,0.0736,0.0756,0.0777.

Comment: Using the first column of 0.0600, 0.0690, 0.0750, 0.0801, 0.0841, 0.0857, 0.0904, then restore (or calculate) the whole triangle by using the formula.